# Manipulate mapping on lists

Tags: list-manipulation, manipulate, string-manipulation, map

For some function f, consider the following expression:

```
 f[2] f[5] - f[1] f[2] f[5] - f[2] f[3] f[5] + f[1] f[2] f[3] f[5] - f[2] f[4] f[5] + f[1] f[2] f[4] f[5] + f[2] f[3] f[4] f[5] - f[1] f[2] f[3] f[4] f[5]
```

How can I manipulate this expression so that it instead reads:

```
f[2,5] - f[1,2,5] - f[2,3,5] + f[1,2,3,5] - f[2,4,5] + f[1,2,4,5] + f[2,3,4,5] - f[1,2,3,4,5]
```

I.e. the function is now implemented on a list of the individual arguments. I've had a go at trying `Map` to achieve this but with no luck.

**EDIT TO QUESTION**

To make this more meaningful for functions, how can the above string be passed as a single vector. Specifically, how can we obtain the output

```
f[{2,5}] - f[{1,2,5}] - f[{2,3,5}] + f[{1,2,3,5}] - f[{2,4,5}] + f[{1,2,4,5}] + f[{2,3,4,5}] - f[{1,2,3,4,5}],
```

this form can then be applied to a predefined function `f[u]` that operates on the list `u`. The function should also be able to take additional arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using upvalues:

```
Times[f[x__], f[y__]] ^:= f[x, y]
```

and then evaluating the expression `f[2] f[5] - f[1] f[2] f[5] - ...` again.

You could also do it without modifying `f` and using `ReplaceRepeated` (`//.`):

```
expr //. Times[f[x__], f[y__]] :> f[x, y]
```

Comment: This works great. Sometimes, it doesn't apply the same ordering. I.e. `f[2] f[3] f[5] //. Times[f[x__], f[y__]] :> f[x, y]` gives `f[5, 2, 3]` not `f[2, 3,5]`. Is there a simple fix for this?

Comment: @Sid - Once you have defined `UpValues` for `f` you do not need to use `/.` or `//.` If you want the arguments ordered use `ClearAll[f]; Times[f[x__], f[y__]] ^:= f @@ Sort[{x, y}]` Then just evaluate `f[2] f[3] f[5]` and the result will be `f[2, 3, 5]`

Comment: @Sid Another way: you can evaluate `SetAttributes[f, Orderless]`, and `f` will thereafter always automatically put its arguments in canonical order (the same ordering `Times` uses).

Comment: @BobHanlon, how can the solution be edited to pass lists to the function f? I.e. see edit to the question

Comment: @Sid `expr //. Times[f[x__], f[y__]] :> f[x, y] /. f[x__] :> f[{x}]`

Comment: @Sid Or `expr //. Times[f[x__], f[y__]] :> f[x, y] /. f :> (f@*List)`

Comment: Define upvalue as `Times[f[x__], f[y__]] ^:= f@Sort[Flatten@{x, y}]` then evaluate your expressions.